# DVD burner laser identification

Tags: identification, laser, optoelectronics, laser-diode

I just disassembled the DVD writer from a laptop and scavenged some parts. Around where the laser and mirrors and opto stuff are packed together, I extracted these parts.

Which one is the laser diode itself? How can I test it? (What voltage/current?)

All these parts were around mirrors/coated glasses. The first one was exactly under where the DVD would sit.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: None of them *are* the laser. One of them may *contain* the laser but the pics are so bad I'm not going to guess which.

Comment: Under the lens? Dig deeper?

Comment: These are all that were there. The rest were plastic parts and positioning mechanism parts. Under the lens was a piece of bluish coated glass facing the dvd surface

Comment: Also, the second image, inside the hole in the metal chunk (heat sink?), there's a little flat surface similar to those found in laser toys. But its barely visible.

Comment: Laser diodes scavenged from DVD players - especially *writers* - can be really dangerous! Take care!